# Entity Framework 5 where returning whole dataset before filtering results

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have an abstract class which gets implemented for all of my repositories - within there I have a property which returns a collection:

```
protected readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetSelection(Func<T, bool> where)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where);
}
```

Repo:

```
public class PostcodeDataRepository : EntityRepositoryBase<PostcodeData>, IPostcodeDataRepository
{
    // Constructor in here
}
```

Now this works great:

```
var postcodeData = postcodeRespoistory.GetSelection(x=>x.Postcode == "SW1A 2TT");
```

(Yes it's uk postcode data, and yes there are nearly 2m rows in the table)

This works great but my problem is returning all of the data only for the application to then filter it is causing some performance issues (as you would expect!).  I used from MiniProfiler and EFProf to confirm that it is effectively doing a `select * from PostcodeData` which isn't what I want it to do.

Has anyone any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` predicate:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetSelection(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where);
}
```

Comment: I could kiss you! Perfect answer!